# How Will API's interpret Calls from my Website? Python/Django Website Project

Tags: python, django

I'm building a website using Django (not sure if this is relevant) and Python, which allows players of a video game to get their game-histories. This involves pulling information from the API for the game, using a function like this below, where "url" is the url endpoint for the API:

```
def API_Call(url):
#dictionary to hold extra headers
HEADERS = {"X-API-Key":'myapikey'}

#make request
try:
    r = requests.get(url, headers=HEADERS, timeout=5)

    return r.json()

except request.exceptions.RequestException as e:

    return {"ErrorCode":"Generic Request Exception"}

except request.exceptions.HTTPError as e:

    return {"ErrorCode": "HTTPError"}


except request.exceptions.Timeout as e:

    return {"ErrorCode": "Timeout"}
```

The API I call has rate limits imposed (something like 200/10 minutes from a single IP address), and I was hoping for some direction or help in understanding how this will work. That is, if I have 10 users log onto the website at the same time, and try to pull histories, will the API view all requests as coming from the same IP address? Or will it see it coming from 10 different IP addresses? If the former, is there a way to have the user's computer do the requests?

Sorry if the above question is too vague; if other specific information would help please let me know. I'm very new to website-building, and I'm really just hacking it so far, figuring out piece by piece what I need to accomplish various goals. I'm also still in a very basic testing mode, and have not completely figured out where/how to actually launch the website (if that matters).

Comment: But if the rate limits are, as the OP writes, on scale of 200/10 minutes from a single IP, then your 10 users all logging into YOUR website and then initiating calls to the target will cause it to see all of those users coming from 1 (ONE) IP address. To make that work differently, you would have to either do some fancy networking involving multiple IPs on your server and managing that, or off loading the call to the user, e.g., from their browser or from a fat client.

Comment: (This was not "@Shawn Mehan", there was an earlier comment I was responding to)Thanks for the response. I'm pretty sure this particular API is per-IP address, so I guess maybe my question was unclear. Suppose I have a button on my website that makes a call to the API. And then suppose two users simultaneously hit that button. Will each request have a separate IP address (i.e. of the user) or will each request have the IP address of whatever server is hosting my website?

Comment: Not exactly on-topic, but for this use case you should look at caching the API responses for a period of time to reduce the number of requests your web app makes. Django's caching system is pretty easy to use.

Comment: Thanks Matthew. My current model stores a mini-version of the game stats in a database (with just the stats of interest) after a request to the API. So if a match has already been pulled, and another user tries to pull it, it won't have to go to the API. But my follow up question is, since I didn't think about this, does this approach seem problematic in any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your webserver makes calls to the game API, then the server running the API will see all those request as coming from one IP address, being the address of your server. It doesn't matter whether those requests were performed in a cron job or by requests from a dozen different users, since it is always your server that communicates to the game servers.

There is a way to make a user's computer do the request, but then it will become a bit hacky. You either have to use an AJAX request, but that will only work if the server API responds with the right headers that allow cross domain AJAX calls. Or you'll have to hack something together using iframes or fake images, but then things will become ugly quite quickly.

Comment: Thanks Golez. I accepted as I think this exactly answered my question. I also don't want to get into anything complicated because, as you said, this can get quite ugly. That said, do you have any suggestions as how to manage requests then? That is, how to have the website know what the current #of requests made in the last 10 seconds was, or something to that effect? I'm not expecting a huge number of visitors, but you never know, and I keep thinking I'm going to put this out there and it's just going to break as soon as it's up.

Comment: If you log the requests you make into a database, you can check the history of the past 10 minutes to see if you have got any requests left. Also, if the API calls return the same result for each of your visitors (not user specific) you could cache the result of the API call on your own server and only do the actual request to the API if more than X minutes have passed since you cached it.